# Unable to access wp admin panel

Tags: wordpress

[Click here for screenshot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kAgk.jpg)

Hello, One of my client create Wordpress Login of his website for me. When i try to open wp-admin page to login i got a popup which says to enter username and password first as it restricted site.

Then i try to reset the password got a reset email click on the link to reset password then again got that popup as show in the attached email, How can we resolve that issue.

Its working fine at client end.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an issue with wordpress.

This is the password prompt from a .htaccess file.
It has different login and password.

You'll have to ask your client for those credentials as well.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have the FTP details and i check for the htaccess file, there is no other code than default wordpress.